# analyzing MSP430 code

Tags: assembly, gdb, msp430

so if had the following statements in assembly for the msp430 with the rf2500 chip

```
0x0000c06a <+44>: 3f 40 22 00 mov  #34, r15; 0x0022
```

and

```
0x0000c07c <+62>: 3e 53      add #-1, r14; r3 As==11
```

how many bytes does each instruction occupy?

Answer (score 2):

The values of the six bytes are shown after the address:

```
                   ___________
0x0000c06a <+44>:  3f 40 22 00  mov  #34, r15; 0x0022
0x0000c07c <+62>:  3e 53        add  #-1, r14; r3 As==11
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: so I would just add all those hex numbers together and divide by 8?

Comment: or would it just be 4 for the first and 2 for the second?